Strange Unsolved Cipher on Youtube from 2014
I recently came across a strange YouTube channel from 2014 called Arcus Grid, containing a puzzle which has seemingly never been solved. It's been posted to Reddit a couple of times, but nobody has ever really gotten anywhere with it. I haven't had any luck decoding it, or even identifying what kind of cipher it is. I would greatly appreciate any guidance on cipher identification (or even better, a solution).
The channel consists of 96 6-second videos, like this one. Here's a GIF of what the videos look like.

There are always six squares that show up, in any of 7 colors (think ROYGBIV).
In each video, there is also Morse code playing in the background. The Morse code always has the following format:

There are 18 characters per video,
The Morse code is split into 6 groups of 3 characters
The first character is always a letter A-F
The second character is always a number 1-6
The third character is always one of ROYGBIV

For example, in the first video, it is C5V A3O E3O E5R B4G F6B.
My first thought was that it could be a Polybius cipher, though that has only produced gibberish. Turning attention to the Morse, it seems like it HAS to be coordinates to the grid, along with an associated color. Yet, I cannot figure out how to integrate the Morse with the grid. Could the visuals be a key for the Morse? I'm quite stumped.
Here are transcriptions for the first 10 videos on the channel:
Visuals (with A-F being the x-coordinate left to right and 1-6 being the y-coordinate top-to-bottom):

A6Y F5B F2B B3R D5G E2I
F5B E3B D6Y A4V D6G A1Y
B6I E5V F1O F5G C5B D1R
E6O A1Y A6Y C5B D3V F3R
D6G B5Y D1I B2R B6I F5G
C5B F2G A5Y D4I B3V B2O
D2Y A2B A6G F5B D6R E2I
A4O A3Y D6R D1V F3B C6G
F5B C3Y D5I A1Y B1Y B1G
D3V B6R A3Y E2O E3G E6I

Morse:

C5V A3O E3O E5R B4G F6B
A3O D2Y E1G F6G E1B C3G
C6O F5R B1Y D3B A3V A6R
A6O C3G C5V A1I D4Y D4R
E1R C4G A6R B3I C6O D3B
A5Y E3O C5G B4V A4I E4Y
B3R B4G B5B A3O E4G D3V
E3G B1B E4G F3R D4G D1O
A3O D6V A3R C3G F1Y F5O
D4Y C3Y B1B E5O E3R A2Y

A full transcription is available here.
